# How to authenticate gocql to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, authentication, aws-sdk-go, aws-sdk-go-v2

I have a Go service that needs to connect Keyspaces on AWS. My pod has a role and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` env vars.

I want to use aws SDK v2. What credential provider should I use? `ec2rolecreds` or other one (maybe `stscreds`)?

I tried to implement example from [here](https://aws.github.io/aws-sdk-go-v2/docs/migrating/#amazon-ec2-iam-role-credentials). But I get an error

```
no EC2 IMDS role found, operation error ec2imds: GetMetadata, request canceled, context deadline exceeded
```

Where can I find working example and more explanations?

**UPDATE**

Now my code looks like this:

```golang
awsCfg, err := awsConfig.LoadDefaultConfig(ctx)
if err != nil {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to load AWS config: %w", err)
}

imdsClient := imds.NewFromConfig(awsCfg)

appCreds := aws.NewCredentialsCache(ec2rolecreds.New(func(options *ec2rolecreds.Options) {
        options.Client = imdsClient
}))
cluster := gocql.NewCluster(cassandraHost)

auth := sigv4.NewAwsAuthenticator()
auth.SessionToken = value.SessionToken
auth.AccessKeyId = value.AccessKeyID
auth.SecretAccessKey = value.SecretAccessKey

cluster.Authenticator = auth

session, err := cluster.CreateSession()
```

`Retrieve()` returns an error

```
no EC2 IMDS role found, operation error ec2imds: GetMetadata, exceeded maximum number of attempts, 3, request send failed, Get \"http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/\": dial tcp 169.254.169.254:80: connect: host is down
```

**UPDATE 2**

In the same environment AWS SDK v1 works ok. So physically AWS endpoint is available.

```golang
session, err := aws_sess.NewSession()
if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("failed to create AWS session: %w", err)
}

creds := credentialsV1.NewChainCredentials(
    []credentialsV1.Provider{
        &credentialsV1.EnvProvider{},
        &ec2rolecredsV1.EC2RoleProvider{
            Client: ec2metadataV1.New(session),
    }})

value, getErr := creds.Get()
```

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: I updated post with the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`no EC2 IMDS role found, operation error ec2imds: GetMetadata, exceeded maximum number of attempts, 3, request send failed, Get \"http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/\": dial tcp 169.254.169.254:80: connect: host is down`

Your snippet of code is attempting to use the EC2 instance meta-data service to read an IAM role to use. For that to work, you need to be able to communicate with it, and the role must be attached to the instance.

Is your Go service running on an EC2 instance? If not, that would explain your error. If it is, make sure the process or container has appropriate network access (eg: network namespace) to communicate with 169.254.169.254.

Comment: when I use SDK v1 in the same environment it can get everything. Here's a code example:
```
session, err := aws_sess.NewSession()
 if err != nil {
  return fmt.Errorf("failed to create AWS session: %w", err)
 }

 creds := credentialsV1.NewChainCredentials(
  []credentialsV1.Provider{
   &credentialsV1.EnvProvider{},
   &ec2rolecredsV1.EC2RoleProvider{
    Client: ec2metadataV1.New(session),
   },
  },
 )

 value, getErr := creds.Get()
```

Comment: please take a look at update 2